# Errors in the Unity project immediately upon creation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create a regular 2d project on the Unity engine. After creating the project, it immediately has errors as in the screenshot.
I couldn't find how to solve it. Reinstalling the Unity did not help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd1zD.png)

Comment: Close Unity. Delete the Library folder.  Reopen the project in Unity

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Are we talking about a _new new_ project or a new project after you have imported something?

Comment: just a new project

Comment: I can confirm that I have a **com.unity.burst@1.6.0** and **com.unity.burst@1.6.5** by default in my **Unity 2021.2.1f1** 3D and 2D projects respectively. What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I use 2021.3.9f1, in 3d projects everything works fine, in 2d there is such an error as I wrote above.